# Trying to deploy docanno to Azure

Tags: azure, deployment, doccano

New to Azure and looking for some support. I'd like to deploy docanno https://github.com/chakki-works/doccano to the free school/work subscription I have for Microsoft Azure.

I have been totally unsuccessful so far. On the docanno page for deploying to Azure it states that it uses Web App for Containers + PostgreSQL database - do these come with the free account for Azure? The Web App for Containers page reads that my subcription does not include that.

I'd appreciate any help here and it's probably really apparent I am new to this so I apologise if this message is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to deploy doccano in my Azure subscription, and I found the reason why you can't have progress. The App Service SKU starts from B1, that is the virtual machine family, this machine is not free, you need to pay to use it, the value is not too much, however a free account will not have sucess to deploy this way. What can you do is to deploy this application manually, however It's not to simple to do this, because is your first time using Azure. It would takes you almost 1 hour. If you need any help fell free to contact me back.